# Merge 1 line with multiple lines in a text file in bash

Tags: bash, shell, solaris

I have a text file with the following pattern.

```
Heading A
 zone zonename1;
 zone zonename2;
 zone zonename3;

Heading B
 zone zonename4;
 zone zonename5;
```

**Desired Output:**

```
  zone zonename1;Heading A;
  zone zonename2;Heading A;
  zone zonename3;Heading A;
  zone zonename4;Heading B;
  zone zonename5;Heading B;
```

Search for the word "zone" and get the respective heading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following awk is here to help you. on a Solaris/SunOS system, change `awk` to `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk` , `/usr/xpg6/bin/awk` , or `nawk`

```
awk '/^Heading/{val=$0;next} NF{print $0,val";"}'  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
 zone zonename1; Heading A;
 zone zonename2; Heading A;
 zone zonename3; Heading A;
 zone zonename4; Heading B;
 zone zonename5; Heading B;
```

Comment: awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: bailing out near line 1
getting this error

Comment: @RadhikaKandasamy,  on a Solaris/SunOS system, change awk to /usr/xpg4/bin/awk , /usr/xpg6/bin/awk , or nawk \

Comment: Working. Thanks :)

Comment: @RadhikaKandasamy, your welcome,glad that it helped you, keep learning keep sharing knowledge, cheers.

Comment: But it is adding to other lines as well. It should stop once empty line is caught. any suggestions?

Comment: @RadhikaKandasamy, ideally it shouldn't print any line when a line is empty, that is why I have written NF there,please post input and output where it is inserting, will look into it.

Comment: It is deleting empty lines and adding "Heading A" to the lines until Heading B is caught